# Why isn't the C++ syntax for a string loop used in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++

**EDIT:** I originally thought the following syntax did not work because of a typo in my code and the fact that I have not seen it used in Javascript.  I am mainly interested in why I don't see this syntax.

I see strings being looped through like so in C++:

```
char s[] = "char";                                                                                                                            
for(int i = 0; s[i]; ++i) {
  printf("it is a %c\n", s[i]); 
}
```

Why isn't the same syntax, (except just defining the string as `s = 'string';`                                                                 used in Javascript?

i.e.

```
  s = "char";                                                                                                                                                                                      
  for(var i = 0; s[i]; i++){
   console.log("it is a " + s[i]);
}
```

Is this just a matter of convention?

Comment: In Javascript, string is not a vector (or array), so `s[i]` is `undefined`

Comment: It *does* work, except you're not printing the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

To loop in string, use "length" property.

```
var s = "char";                                                                                                                                                                                      
  for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
   console.log("it is a " + s[i]);
}
```

EDIT:
To check with your initial condition ...

```
var s = "char";                                                                                                                                                                                      
  for(var i = 0; s[i] != undefined; i++){
    console.log("it is a " + s[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Also note that it should be `var s` instead of just `s`

Comment: @ThibaultBach code will give the error. You have extra `"` in console.

Comment: Woot ... so tied =D Thanks !

Comment: I am well aware this works, and how to loop in Javascript, my question was why `s[i]` does not work as the testing condition in the loop.

Comment: Oh sorry, i can't understand you're question. So ... you're s[i] condition doesn't work because in javascript , where array dimension or variable doesn't exist, JS doesn't return "false" but "undefined". Look my edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var s="char";
for(var i = 0; s[i]; i++){
   alert("it is a "+s[i]);
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uLqbb2y1/).**

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt return undefined. Im getting output as:

```
    it is a s[i]
    it is a s[i]
    it is a s[i] 
    it is a s[i]
```

That's because s[i] is being treated as characters rather than the  i-th element of the s array.

Instead use line 3 as:

```
    console.log("it is a " + s[i]);
```